# Change browser URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a path

```
https://jobs.com/head-of-sales
```

How can I change it to

```
https://jobs.com/careers/head-of-sales
```

I do not have a careers folder actually.
I just need to change the path

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rule file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to do a reasonable amount of research, _before_ you come asking here. URL rewriting is an already broadly discussed and documented topic - so please don’t just come here with a basic “how to” question, but show some initial effort. This should come at least with an _attempt_ you made. We are happy to help if you can not fully get there on your own, but we are not here to just give you code.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?careers/head-of-sales$ /head-of-sales [END]
```

If you also want to redirect browsers (still) using the "old" URL that variant should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?head-of-sales$ /careers/head-of-sales [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?careers/head-of-sales$ /head-of-sales [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` temporary redirection and only change that to a `R=301` permanent redirection later, once you are sure everything works as expected. That prevents nasty caching issues.

You can implement above rules in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but that comes with a performance penalty.

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server...